# Eclipse Reading File From Resource NullPointerException

Tags: java, eclipse, resources, getresource

I am a newb so please don't hit me too hard.  I have been trying to figure this out for like 2 days now reading posts and blogs and I keep getting a NullPointerException error and I cannot figure out why it will not reach the files.  Below I am showing the layout of my folders, I have tried this multiple ways putting resource folder inside the src folder or outside and I still get the same error.

[image: Folder Config]

Here is my code I am using.

```
package com;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class ClasspathFileReader
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
        String fileName = "resource/SrcPath.txt";
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());


        //Read File Content
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        System.out.println(content);
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ClasspathFileReader.main(ClasspathFileReader.java:14)
```

Comment: can we see the stack trace?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Which line you are getting NPE?

Comment: Edited with stack trace, Thanks @Solace

Comment: @yılmaz Line 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two comments on your code:

- As pointed out by @yilmaz, rename your file as `SrcPath.txt`. Just use the `rename` option in `eclipse`.
- The getResource() searches for the `file` relative to your `.class` file. Thus, create a package `resource` inside your `src` folder and save your `SrcPath.txt` file here.

Comment: This worked, THANK YOU!  I need to spend some more time learning folder and package structure and stuff but put the txt file in a package `resource` inside the `src` folder worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your file (`SrcPath`) doesn't end up with `.txt` extension according to screenshot. Give it a try.

Comment: You are correct and I did notice this because when I go to the directory in eclipse-workspace and find the files they are not saved as txt but as "File".  I thought this may be my issue but when I make a txt file in notepad and save it in the folder it wont appear in Eclipse.  How can I get a txt file in there?

Comment: Create a new txt file and drag or paste it into package explorer of eclipse, you should see your file now in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Using  classloader your file should be in your class folder i.e src. Put your SrcPath.txt in src folder and it will work just fine.